# how to match bigger word first, from multiple words separated by OR operator in RegExp ? using java script

Tags: javascript, regex, str-replace, string-matching, regexp-replace

I need a regex to first match a numbers with 'px' after it, and  then match remaining numbers having 'p' after it.
I want to replace parts of string, that are number or a number having 'p' or 'px' after it by '*' character.

a regexp i tried `/\d+(\.\d+)?(p|px)?/g` , but its not matching 'px' its only matching 'p'.

- example string, before any replacements to it.: 12pxy...12py...12px...12ppx...12...12ypx
- here parts that should be replaced are in bold: **12px**y...**12p**y...**12px**...**12p**px...**12**...**12**ypx
- expected result after doing all replacements : *y...*y...*...*px...*...*ypx

following code that I tried, is replacing the number and 'p' but not 'px'.

```js
str = "12pxy...12py...12px...12ppx...12...12ypx";

replaced_str = str.replace(/\d+(\.\d+)?(p|px)?/g, '*');

console.log(replaced_str); 
// output is: *xy...*y...*x...*px...*...*ypx
// I wanted : *y...*y...*...*px...*...*ypx
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what are you building? Why that specific output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> its not matching 'px' its only matching 'p'

That is because the `(p|px)?` alternation is not anchored at the pattern end, and the first alternative *always* wins since `p` is a prefix of `px`, see ["*Remember That The Regex Engine Is Eager*"](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html#eager).

What you can do is swap the alternatives, `(px|p)?`, or re-write `(?:px?)?`. Also, you can use non-capturing groups here to avoid extra overhead related to capture mmemory allocation:

```js
str = "12pxy...12py...12px...12ppx...12...12ypx";
replaced_str = str.replace(/\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:px?)?/g, '*');
console.log(replaced_str); 
// output: *y...*y...*...*px...*...*ypx
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pJS609/1). *Details*:

- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `(?:\.\d+)?` - an optional occurrence of a dot and one or more digits
- `(?:px?)?` - an optional occurrence of `p` followed with an optional `x`.

Answer (score 2):

For the given example, you could match 1+ digits followed by an optional p and an optional x.

```
\d+p?x?
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/e0iwLt/1)

Also matching a decimal part:

```
\d+(?:\.\d+)?p?x?
```

The pattern matches:

- `\d+` Match 1+ digits
- `(?:\.\d+)?` Match an optional decimal part
- `p?x?` Match an optional `p` and optional `x`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AbTNU8/1/)

And replace with an `*`

```js
str = "12pxy...12py...12px...12ppx...12...12ypx";

replaced_str = str.replace(/\d+p?x?/g, '*');
console.log(replaced_str);
```

Output

```
*y...*y...*...*px...*...*ypx
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, I used it but I am accepting  @Wiktor answer because it is answering to my thought process from which the question came.